# Is it possible to use ftp_connect() for more than one page?

Tags: php, session

I have 3-4 pages of my website that uses ftp_connect(), currently I connect on every single pageload and it takes time to load the pages.

Is it possible to do a single ftp_connect and use that on all pages? Like store it in a session or something?

Don't know if it's ftp_connets()'s fault that it sometimes take 5-10 seconds to load a page.

Comment: Why do you need to do it on every page? Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do `ftp_connect` on one page and pass it on to other pages.

Yes, the 4 second delay is most probably `ftp_connect` connecting to the remote server.

Comment: What I thought :( Thanks for the anwer :)